# Python boto Purging Aws old Ebs Snapshots "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'datetime.timedelta'"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, amazon-ebs

I'm trying to write a python script to delete ebs snapshots which are 14 days old. problem is i could not able to display 2 weeks old date and compare that with current date. Below is my code

```
import boto
import dateutil.relativedelta
from boto.exception import EC2ResponseError
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region(
    'us-east-1',
    aws_access_key_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    aws_secret_access_key = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy',
 )

snaps = conn.get_all_snapshots()

for list in snaps:
    old_date = list.start_time - timedelta(days=14)
    if list.start_time (is less than or equal to) old_date:
       print conn.delete_snapshots(list.id)
```

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/swaroop/Documents/My_python/display_snapshots.py", line 28, in 
    old_date = list.start_time - timedelta(days=14)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'unicode' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Note: Snapshots display date format this way: 2013-12-19T11:11:43.000Z

### Thanks

Swaroop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `list.start_time` returns start datetime as unicode string.

You need to convert it to datetime.timedelta

like

```
from dateutil import parser
```

and

```
for snap in snaps:
    limit = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=14)
    if parser.parse(snap.start_time).date() <= limit.date():
        #do your filter stuff here
        print conn.delete_snapshot(snap.id)
```

Note: First you can try with `print snap.id`, if it will return a valid result then you can do `print conn.delete_snapshot(snap.id)`

Comment: Thank you for the help syed, its throwing error When i executed with conn.delete_snapshots(snap.id) Error:  "AttributeError: 'EC2Connection' object has no attribute 'delete_snapshots'

Comment: Sorry, try with `conn.delete_snapshot(snap.id)`

Comment: Thank you so much syed. That worked like charm. Unfortunately i could not able to vote this as i'm new to stackoverflow and has less reputation. Thanks again